# Apply heatmap on video with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, heatmap

I want to write a code that will apply heatmap on the video on places where there is a movement.
I wrote a code that detects movement, with contours but I do not know how to make heat map.

This is the code that I have

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# upload video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test_video.mp4')

#reading two frames
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()

while cap.isOpened():

     # get diference between two frames
     diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)

     # convert diference in gray
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

     # bluring and treshold
     blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
     _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

     dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 3)

     # define contours
     contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     
     # draw contours
     cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 1)

     # show frames
     cv2.imshow('frame', frame1)
     frame1 = frame2
     ret, frame2 = cap.read()

     if cv2.waitKey(60) == 60:
          break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I have seen this link: [Build a Motion Heatmap Video Using OpenCV With Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-motion-heatmap-videousing-opencv-with-python-fd806e8a2340). And I wanted to reproduce the code, but a lot of stuff such as `fourcc`, `image_folder`, and `images` is not defined, so I tried to do it the other way.

Can you help me with this? Basically, I want to apply the heatmap to the video where there is a movement.

Comment: Have you searched Google for examples on still images?

Comment: yes, but what that have to do with my question/

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question. Many heat maps are available. And you apply it using cv2.applyColorMap.

Comment: If you are trying to create a heat map from the amount of motion, then pick some color and make the intensity of the color proportional to the distance moved at each pixel in your image. If you only know that there is a change, then I guess your heat map would be a binary image.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the link. That is something else outside my expertise.

Comment: Note that the code from towardsdatascience you're referring to is available on github: https://github.com/robertosannazzaro/motion-heatmap-opencv. You can git clone it, add a "frames" folder and try that code and see how it works. You'll also have to pip install the "progress" module and the result is not exactly what is shown (probably an opencv version mismatch) but it (kind of) works.

Comment: @nathancy Thanks! But that post is asking to convert a static image into a heatmap, whereas this post is asking to convert a video, putting the frame-by-frame transition into account.

Comment: @nathancy By the way, if you can find another solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70556110/13552470) feel free to post.

Comment: @AnnZen I would have used [salient object detection using U-2 Net](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net#usage-for-salient-object-detection) which would give a mask then do some morphological operations to clean up the excess noise, find contours, draw the perfect outline, and/or bitwise_and to get the extracted result. Looks like someone else already had the same idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an idea. You know how you loop through the frames of a video using opencv, right? Well, for each frame the `while` loop is at, have the frame that would come after the current frame stored in a variable, and compare the difference between the current frame and the future frame.

With the difference between the two frames, you can detect the contours of the movement. Let's say we draw the contours on the image with green.

Have a blank array defined before the `while` loop to be the heat map; every iteration of the loop, add a certain amount to every coordinate of the heat map where the coordinate is green on the frame, and remove a certain amount from the heat map where the coordinate is not green on the image.

1. Import the necessary modules:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function to process the difference between two frames into something that will allow better detection of contours for our case. The values can be tweaked according to your needs:

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 25)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 5, 50)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=4)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode
```

3. Define a function that will take in a processed image of the difference between two frames, and the image you want the contours to be drawn on. It will return the image with the contours (green) drawn on it:

```
def get_contours(img, img_original):
    img_contours = img_original.copy()
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1) 
    return img_contours
```

4. Define your capture device, and read two frames before the `while` loop; the first one to be the present frame of each iteration of the `while` loop, and the second to be the future frame of each iteration of the `while` loop. Also, define the blank image for the heat map, `heat_map`:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Bar fight security cam.mp4")

success, img1 = cap.read()
success, img2 = cap.read()
heat_map = np.zeros(img1.shape[:-1])
```

5. In the `while` loop, find the difference between the two frames and get the current frame of each loop with the contours from the difference drawn on it:

```
while success:
    diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
    img_contours = get_contours(process(diff), img1)
```

6. Add a number, say `3`, to every coordinate of the `heat_map` where it is green on the image returned by the `get_contours` function defined earlier, and subtract 3 from every coordinate of the `heat_map` where it is not green on the image. To make sure that no colors result in channel values less than `0` and greater than `255`, apply the boundaries to the heat map:

```
    heat_map[np.all(img_contours == [0, 255, 0], 2)] += 3
    heat_map[np.any(img_contours != [0, 255, 0], 2)] -= 3
    heat_map[heat_map < 0] = 0
    heat_map[heat_map > 255] = 255
```

7. Convert the `heat_map` array to a grayscale image, and then to a heat ma image:

```
    img_mapped = cv2.applyColorMap(heat_map.astype('uint8'), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

8. Finally, show the frames and retrieve the frames for the next iteration:

```
    cv2.imshow("Original", img1)
    cv2.imshow("Heat Map", img_mapped)
    
    img1 = img2
    success, img2 = cap.read()
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

Altogether:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 25)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 5, 50)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=4)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode

def get_contours(img, img_original):
    img_contours = img_original.copy()
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1) 
    # If you want to omit smaller contours, loop through the detected contours, and only draw them on the image if they are at least a specific area. Don't forget to remove the line above if you choose the below block of code.
    # for cnt in contours: 
    #     if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 500:
    #         cv2.drawContours(img_contours, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), -1) 

    return img_contours

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Bar fight security cam.mp4")

success, img1 = cap.read()
success, img2 = cap.read()
heat_map = np.zeros(img1.shape[:-1])

while success:
    diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
    img_contours = get_contours(process(diff), img1)

    heat_map[np.all(img_contours == [0, 255, 0], 2)] += 3 # The 3 can be tweaked depending on how fast you want the colors to respond
    heat_map[np.any(img_contours != [0, 255, 0], 2)] -= 3
    heat_map[heat_map < 0] = 0
    heat_map[heat_map > 255] = 255

    img_mapped = cv2.applyColorMap(heat_map.astype('uint8'), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

#    img1[heat_map > 160] = img_mapped[heat_map > 160] Use this line to draw the heat map on the original video at a specific temperature range. For this it's where ever the temperature is above 160 (min is 0 and max is 255)

    cv2.imshow("Original", img1)
    cv2.imshow("Heat Map", img_mapped)
    
    img1 = img2
    success, img2 = cap.read()
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have three questions...can you please explain me part 6, why number 3? And is it possible to apply heatmap (only orange and red color) on original video?
And third, is it possible to apply heatmap only on rapid movement, or big movements, I mean increasing threshold for movement?

Comment: Basically, I would like to have orange/red color only when fight starts.